# Finding the previous value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `queue` with values.

```
id name
1  apple
2  mango
3  banana  -- (I assumed this name, don't remember it exactly)
```

But I accidentally changed it to be

```
id name
1  apple
2  mango
3  John
```

So I reverted it back to

```
id name
1  apple
2  mango
3  banana
```

But now came to know that name is not banana for `id=3`. How can I know what used to be there before I changed it?

Comment: Have you got a backup?

Comment: Without knowing what kind of Database or if wether there's a backup. An alternative but tedious method could be to look for a recent generated report (before the change) that drew also data from that table and search for the id & name in there.

Comment: I am using `sql server management studio`

Comment: At one place I worked there were a lot of reference tables that all had a correspondent history table. Via triggers the updates/deletes/inserts were all put into those history tables together with who/when made the change.  It made it easier to verify who screwed with the reference data afterwards.

Comment: Any logging? Can you ask the DBA to fix it?

Comment: You need to maintain log tables for all DML operation to track what and when your data is getting changed.

Comment: without using the backup or without having some kind of trigger-based-history you will NOT get that value. The server does not store a history itself

Answer (score 2):

You can read the transaction log ,if your database is in full recovery model..

**Demo below.**.

```
create table test4
(
name varchar(10)
)

insert into test4
select 'abc'
union all
select 'def'

---updated mistakenly
update test4
set name='def' where name='abc'

select [Current LSN], [Operation], [Transaction ID], 
    [Transaction SID], [Begin Time], [End Time],
    [Num Elements], [RowLog Contents 0], [RowLog Contents 1], [RowLog Contents 2],
    [RowLog Contents 3], [RowLog Contents 4]
    from fn_dblog(null, null)
    where  [Transaction ID]='0000:00050df7'


    select cast(0x616263 as varchar(20))--'abc--rowlogcontent0 value
```

**Few points to note:**
1.You can go to exact table in Tlog and look for an update  by querying like below

```
select * from fn_dblog(null,null)
    where  allocunitname='name of your table' and operation='LOP_MODIFY_ROW'
```

2.For an update `Rowlogcontent0` will contain before image and `rowlogcontent1` will contain after image

**References and further reading:**
http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/